# Error while loading a music file in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build a music player using Python Tkinter, but I really facing issues while I set the song path it seems some errors.

Here is my code:

```
    song = song_box.get(ACTIVE)
    song = f'C:/Users/parve/PycharmProjects/gf/songs/{song}.ogg'
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
```

Here is the error I face:

```
     File "C:/Users/parve/PycharmProjects/gf/music.py", line 25, in play
     pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
     pygame.error: Failed loading libvorbisfile-3.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the libvorbisfile-3.dll, or you have the wrong version.

Comment: The DLL should be included in `pygame` module.  Try reinstall `pygame`.

Comment: I have tried it but the result is the same.

Comment: Do you install `pygame` inside PyCharm virtual environment?  I have no such issue with my PyCharm environment.

Comment: Yes! I just install it from the terminal.

Comment: See [my pycharm virtual environment](https://imgur.com/JIgnAl2).  You can see that the file `libvorbisfile-3.dll` is in the file list on the project tab and the demo `main.py` can be executed without error.

Comment: Nothing changes the same things happens.